# Error install Android SDK in Appcelerator 2017

Tags: android, sdk, titanium, appcelerator

There is a problem in the installation of Appcelerator. When you download the Android SDK, you receive the error. How to fix it?

> ```
> The following data will be sent:
>
> ------
> STATUS
> ------
> pluginId            com.appcelerator.titanium.android.core
> pluginVersion       1.0.0.1478890706
> code                0
> severity            4
> message             (Build 4.8.1.201612050850) [ERROR]  An uncaught exception was thrown!
> ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\android-sdk-win\add-ons'
> fingerprint         18594a85
> stacktrace
>
>
>
> ------
> REPORT
> ------
> name                xxx
> email               xxx
> comment             
> productVersion      xxx
> productName         Appcelerator Studio
> javaRuntimeVersion  1.8.0_131-b11
> osgiWs              win32
> osgiOs              Windows 10
> osgiOsVersion       xxx
> osgiArch            x86
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The Destination Folder should be the same as your Android SDK HOME folder. This path will be required when configuring Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to install Android sdk via Appcelerator Studio. Install Android Studio first. follow this tutorial to install Android Studio https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l26rtc1wKYo&t=219s in your system. Test your sdk by running a simple hello world app first. if it runs perfectly then sdk is properly functioning. I prefer to do it this way because you can point out your problem easily. Whether the problem is occurring in Appcelerator Studio or it is actually your Android Studio that is not installed properly. You will find tons of resource in google if you face problem installing Android Studio in your system or you can just ask it here.
If Android Studio is working properly and you've successfully run hello world app in emulator/device then go ahead to install Appcelerator Studio in your system. Appcelerator Studio will automatically grab your sdk location when you install it or you can manually change the location to your sdk.